# Definition of "telescope"

Tags: meaning

I'm having trouble finding a definition of **telescope** that works for all telescopes (optical, radio, or otherwise). So far, all the definitions I've found only apply to **optical telescopes**.

[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/telescope):

> **telescope**
>   An optical instrument designed to make distant objects appear nearer, containing an arrangement of lenses, or of curved mirrors and lenses, by which rays of light are collected and focused and the resulting image magnified.

[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/telescope):

> **telescope**
>   an optical instrument for making distant objects appear larger and therefore nearer. One of the two principal forms (refracting telescope) consists essentially of an objective lens set into one end of a tube and an adjustable eyepiece or combination of lenses set into the other end of a tube that slides into the first and through which the enlarged object is viewed directly; the other form (reflecting telescope) has a concave mirror that gathers light from the object and focuses it into an adjustable eyepiece or combination of lenses through which the reflection of the object is enlarged and viewed.

These definitions work just fine for optical telescopes, but there are many different types of telescopes, and not all of them fit either definition. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescope#Types),

> [In certain] types of high energy particle telescopes there is no image-forming optical system.

A telescope's optical components seem to be a defining feature, and I'm uncertain how some of these types of telescopes are considered telescopes under the current definition.

Is there another, more generic definition of "telescope" that I've missed?
 If not, is there a reason why the definition of "telescope" hasn't been updated to include a wider range of devices?

Comment: Perhaps some are telescopes by analogy.

Comment: _OED Online_ adds this to the first definition: "Also: an instrument or apparatus of analogous design used to study distant sources of electromagnetic radiation lying outside the visible spectrum."

Comment: Nicely researched question! +1

Comment: 'An instrument capable of focussing' would include all telescopes and microscopes.

Comment: @NigelJ I'm not sure that long-wave radio telescopes focus anything, although they may be directional. The same may be true of microwave telescopes. Even omnidirectional devices are referred to as *radio telescopes*.

Comment: @ermanen Good point. However, even the assertion that all telescopes measure electromagnetic radiation is false as neutrino detectors are sometimes also considered to be telescopes. For example,
 [ANTARES](http://antares.in2p3.fr/): "Astronomy with a **Neutrino Telescope** and Abyss environmental RESearch"

Comment: Photon detection and neutrino detection work similarly, though of course the detectors are vastly different. Both can be considered telescopes. BTW, there is also a verb _telescope_, which means to condense like a collapsing telescope.

Comment: @Vyren: Technology is advancing rapidly, dictionaries are not that fast :) Most detect electromagnetic radiation so that's why it is included in the definition also.

Comment: @Mick: Of course conventional radio telescopes focus radiation. They're parabolic discs, which focus things with mirrors rather than lenses (since there aren't materials that bend radio waves). I guess omnidirectional ones focus the light computationally, so you could argue that the word "focus" doesn't apply to them.

Comment: @PeterShor Long-wave radio telescopes are usually just a lot of wire strung out on poles in a field. Such a device was used to detect the first pulsar (although not to determine its position). Anyway, we are really nit-picking.

Comment: Upon closer inspection, it seems that directional neutrino detectors (such as [ANTARES](http://antares.in2p3.fr/)) are called "telescopes," whereas non-directional neutrino detectors (such as [Borexino](http://borex.lngs.infn.it/)) are just called "detectors." Also, every telescope I've found that's designed to observe anything other than electromagnetic radiation uses EMR somewhere in the detector. [LIGO](https://www.ligo.org/) measures gravitational waves using lasers, neutrino detectors look for photons displaced by neutrinos (or something, not 100% sure), etc. Maybe that's significant...

Comment: The [SKA](https://www.skatelescope.org/aperture-arrays/) gives a nice example of what Mick's talking about (i.e collecting signals with antennae and adding them electronically).  That sort of thing would be tricky to add to a definition in a general dictionary for reasons of space

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/telescope) says that the word *telescope* comes from the Greek words *tele*, meaning *far*, and *skopos*, meaning *watcher*.

And in fact, I can't think of anything called a *telescope* that isn't used for observing something far away. But to make it a more precise definition, you should add that it observes it by using some kind of radiation, since otherwise a Mars lander would qualify as a telescope, which it clearly shouldn't.

The [*Collins Dictionary*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/telescope) has the definition

> 2. any instrument, such as a radio telescope, for collecting, focusing, and detecting electromagnetic radiation from space.

So they *have* updated their definition.

However, we now have telescopes that use neutrinos and gravitational waves, and these don't focus the radiation in any meaningful sense, so removing the words "electromagnetic" and "focusing" from the definition would probably be a good idea.

Answer (score 5):

In astronomy a telescope isn't used so much to make things appear closer as to concentrate a weaker signal to detect fainter objects.

The point of a telescope is to have a larger aperture than your eye and so to collect more light and allow you to see fainter, more distant objects - so Peter Shor's answer is the best.

The Collins definition is a bit off - it doesn't have to be electromagnetic (we have neutrino telescopes) and it doesn't have to focus (interferometers e.g. radio telescopes don't).

Comment: The Collins definition might have been written when there weren't neutrino telescopes, and when radio telescopes were generally composed of parabolic antennas, which definitely focused things. But you're right, it's off now.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that *telescope* is assumed to refer to a device that operates at visible frequencies, since that is what telescopes originally did.  Telescopes that detect frequencies beyond visible spectrum are usually referred to by the frequencies that they detect, e.g. *microwave telescopes*, *radio telescopes*, *infra-red telescopes*, etc. However, they all detect electromagnetic radiation (i.e. photons), albeit at different frequencies (or wavelengths).

Note that dictionary definitions may be somewhat vague:

> **radio telescope** noun [ C ]
>
> a device for receiving, for scientific study, the electromagnetic waves sent out by objects in space such as stars

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/radio-telescope)

This definition is a little misleading, since *radio telescope* normally refers to a device that operates at frequencies below the infra-red spectrum.

Like *microscope*, the term *telescope* is a reasonable catch-all, although its meaning may be misunderstood.

---

Note that there are such things as *neutrino telescopes*. Neutrinos are not a form of electromagnetic radiation, although they are fundamental particles.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to refer to a specialist dictionary.  I have a copy of *The Penguin Dictionary of Physics* copyright 1975 (abridged 1977).

Under *telescope*, definition 1 starts *An optical device for producing a magnified or intensified image of distant objects* and runs to 4 paragraphs, mentioning refracting and reflecting types.

Definition 2 is of interest here, and I quote it in its entirety:

> An electronic device for detecting and amplifying electromagnetic radiation outside the visible region of the spectrum, including the *radio telescope and *electron telescope

(the asterisks indicate terms defined elsewhere in this dictionary).  Note the lack of references to *focussing* in this definition, thus it would include even phased array telescopes like some of the square kilometre array.

---

For those puzzled by the *electron telescope* (as I was) it used a photocathode, high-voltage accelerating grids, and a phosphor screen to image UV and IR.